# Не записываются данные которые пришли через прокидываемый callback через props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю своё приложение react  строго по урокам. Но возникла такая ошибка, целый день пытался разобраться, но понятие не имею почему так происходит. Основная суть в том, что у меня есть функция `addProduct` находящаяся в компоненте `ModalAddProduct`, фактически она просто собирает данные и передаёт их в функцию `addProduct`которая находится в папке redux/state.js, эта функция просто добавляет данные переданные ей через callback в объект `state`, в котором хранятся все продукты. Но проблема в том, что данные не записываются. Хотя при дэбагинге видно, что данные приходят, но не пушутся в массив.

```
export let addProduct = (data) => { //Это в папке redux/state.js . Data это данные которые мы приняли и в этом же файле находится обьект state
debugger;

 state.mainPage.products.push(data);
 rerenderF(state);
}
export default state;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import state from './redux/state';
import {addProduct} from './redux/state';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App state={state} addProduct={addProduct}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Components/Navbar/Nav';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';
import AdminProducts from './Pages/AdminProducts'; 

import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const  App = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
       <Nav></Nav>
       <Route path="/products" 
       render={ () => <AdminProducts products={props.state.mainPage.products} addProduct={props.addProduct}/>} />
       <Footer></Footer>
     </div>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

AdminProduct.js

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <ProductsList products={props.products} addProduct={props.addProduct} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

ProductList.js

```
function ProductList(props) {
    return (
       <div className="container">
           <AddProductButton />
           <ModalAddProduct addProduct={props.addProduct}/>
          <div className="row"> 
               {props.products.map( product => {
                   return <ProductAdminCard  product={product} />
               })}
          </div>
       </div>
    );
}
```

```
import { checkPropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

function ModalAddProduct(props) {
    const urlPhoto = 'https://sun9-56.userapi.com/impg/46d6OEAguHzOvhD8gFvtuaKJpgbB2HdpCrR2wQ/rXhMbv1AJnE.jpg?size=800x800&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=1c6396244ef85dbe1ab426308018ddca';
    let setPrice = React.createRef();
    let setProducer = React.createRef();
    let setType = React.createRef();
    let setSizes = React.createRef();
    let setDescription = React.createRef();
    let setTags = React.createRef();
    let setPhoto = React.createRef();

    const addProduct = () => {
      const data = {
                id: 9,
                "urlPhoto": urlPhoto,
                "price": `${setPrice.current.value}`,
                "producer": `${setProducer.current.value}`,
                "type": `${setType.current.value}`,
                "sizes": `${setSizes.current.value}`,
                "description": `${setDescription.current.value}`,
                "tags": `${setTags.current.value}`
      }
     props.addProduct(data);
     setPrice.current.value = '';
     setProducer.current.value = '';
     setType.current.value = '';
     setSizes.current.value = '';
     setDescription.current.value = '';
     setTags.current.value = '';
    }
    return (
    <div className="modal fade" id="addProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <figure className="figure">
                        <img src={urlPhoto} className="figure-img img-fluid rounded profile-img" alt="photo" />
                      </figure>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="photo">Url photo</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="photo" placeholder="URL" ref={setPhoto} />
                          <label for="price">Price</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="price" placeholder="Enter price" ref={setPrice} />
                          <label for="producer">Producer</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="producer" placeholder="Enter producer" ref={setProducer} />
                          <label for="type">Type</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="type" placeholder="Enter type" ref={setType} />
                          <label for="sizes">Sizes</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="sizes" placeholder="Enter sizes(use ',')" ref={setSizes} />
                          <label for="description">Description</label>
                          <textarea className="form-control" id="description" rows="3" ref={setDescription}></textarea>
                          <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="Enter tags" ref={setTags} />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <button className="btn general-button add-button-modal btn-block" onClick={addProduct}>Add product</button>
                    <button className="btn general-button delete-button btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Canel</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ModalAddProduct;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете показать весь компонент redux/state.js ?

Comment: Только обьект данных state и функция addProduct. Я пробовал с другими данными ,так же ошибка. Причём при дэбагинке, если навести курсов на массив, оно показывает добавленные продукты , но в самом массиве их нет(есть скриншоты). Так же, когда по урокам был добавлен рендеринг при изменииях, приложение показывает товары, но после перезагрузки они исчезают ,так как не записались в массив продуктов.

Comment: Если у вас это state компонента, то туда надо добавлять данные через функцию:   this.setState({
      mainPage.products.push(data)
    });